# Only those whoe have an offer or service(Not Null Value)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables like this

1st table:person

| PID | MOBILE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 234 |
| 3 | 345 |
| 4 | 456 |

2nd table: offer

| PID | of_id | of_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | offer 1 |
| 3 | 12 | offer 2 |
| 3 | 13 | offer 3 |

3td table: service

| PID | ser_id | ser_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | ser 2 |
| 1 | 11 | ser 1 |

I want table like this:

| PID | mobile | of_name | ser_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | offer 1 | ser 1 |
| 2 | 234 |  | ser 2 |
| 3 | 345 | offer 3 |  |
| 3 | 34 | offer 3 |  |

i tried:

```
select distinct p.pid,p.mobile,o.of_name,s.ser_name 
  from person p
left join (select pid,of_name from offer) o on p.pid = o.pid
left join (select pid,ser_name from service) s on p.pid = s.pid
```

but i got:

| PID | mobile | of_name | ser_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | offer 1 | ser 1 |
| 2 | 234 |  | ser 2 |
| 3 | 345 | offer 3 |  |
| 3 | 34 | offer 3 |  |
| 4 | 456 |  |  |

So, My table should only include those who have an offer or service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My table should only include those who have an offer or service.

You can filter to only include the rows where there is either an offer or a service by checking that the `PID` from those tables is not `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT p.pid,
       p.mobile,
       o.of_name,
       s.ser_name 
FROM   person p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN offer o
       ON p.pid = o.pid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN service s
       ON p.pid = s.pid
WHERE  o.pid IS NOT NULL
OR     s.pid IS NOT NULL
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (PID, MOBILE) AS
SELECT 1, 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 234 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 345 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 456 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE offer (PID, of_id, of_name) AS
SELECT 1, 11, 'offer 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 12, 'offer 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 13, 'offer 3' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE service (PID, ser_id, ser_name) AS
SELECT 2, 10, 'ser 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 11, 'ser 1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PID | MOBILE | OF_NAME | SER_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 123 | offer 1 | ser 1 |
> | 3 | 345 | offer 2 | *null* |
> | 3 | 345 | offer 3 | *null* |
> | 2 | 234 | *null* | ser 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=14d0f1fbbfaf7c063d9594ede2f47d99)*

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
with cte as(select p.pid,p.mbl,
o.name as offername,s.name as service_name from person p 
left join offer o on p.pid=o.pid
left join service s on p.pid=s.pid
) select pid,mbl,offername,service_name
from cte where pid in (select pid from offer
union 
select pid from service)
```